# Noun or Verb for Title?

Tags: conventions, title

If I have a page or window that allows the user to manage something, for example a subscription, should the title be "Manage subscription" or "Subscription management?" Which word order gives the best clarity and does this principle apply to other labels (like tabs)?

Comment: This is something that you really need to check with your particular users - Only they will be able to tell you what works best for them.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a page title, use a noun. If it's something that indicates an action, use a verb.

For example; if you go to your management page, call it 'x management'. On that page, when you want to add an item, label the button 'add item'.

Comment: That means if I'm on the main page, I would have a button or link that says "Manage X." When the user presses that and navigates in, it should show "X Management?"

Comment: @Jai I guess it depends if you call a navigation link an action

Answer (score 0):

This article: [The Object-Oriented User. An updated, expanded, roughed-up… | by Sophia V Prater](https://blog.prototypr.io/the-object-oriented-user-52c5bbdb246c) maintains that we think in nouns first and verbs second.

I am not sure though, even if that is the truth, to what extent it matters in titles and whether it has any impact at all.